# ASP.Net MVC Modelbinder & Request.Form is empty even though multipart/MIME was posted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, http, post, jmeter

I have an app that works fine when used normally through a browser.

When attempting to record or playback a JMeter script, the application stops working, and certain pages end up with an empty model. I have confirmed via wireshark that form data is being posted during these requests.

I compared wireshark of a working request to a failing request, and the differences are very minor.

The main one is this

Working:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryyuuSWkmnnXJCTJzw
```

Failing:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=kAbx249hddVWzlxpSVyEMxcpc9waTo; charset=UTF-8
```

The boundary text is modified by the JMeter proxy, and charset=UTF-8 is also added by the proxy.

I confirmed that in the actual MIME data, the correct boundary is used in both cases.

All other headers, cookies, names in the form post, etc are all identical.

When my action is hit, the model is empty (The main model variable is not null, but all properties in that model are default values)

In the debug/immediate window, the Request.Form is empty.

```
? Request.Form
{}
    [System.Web.HttpValueCollection]: {}
    base: {}
    AllKeys: {string[0]}
```

I can make the wireshark captures available for those that think they will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

1. What are the other differences? The above should be critical, boundaries doesn't matter given they match. Encoding - it's 2016 now, every well-behaved application should understand unicode.
2. What happens if you try recording your test via [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206732579-Chrome-Extension) it shouldn't be so "invasive"?

Comment: It was definitely the encoding.  I captured working requests, added the encoding, and it broke.

Apparently sending UTF-8 encoding (without changing the payload at all) causes IIS/ASP.Net to ignore the form post.